# Relativity and absoluteness

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I came across in a book that magnetic field is relative which is not digesting for example consider a charged particle plus Q of mass M is travelling with velocity V in upward direction then if observer 1 being at rest observes it then there will the magnetic field due to the charged particle and due to it will apply force on the objects nearby say A block and if the same charged particle is being observed by the observer 2 which is also travelling upward  with the charged particle with velocity v then there will be no magnetic field produced by the charged particle and therefore no force on the block the same situation when of the two of the words give two different results
How is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that electric field also changes when you go from the one system of reference to the other. In the reference frame where the charge is at rest there is only electric field, while in the system where it moves with constant velocity, there are both electric and magnetic fields, whose effect on a probe is precisely the same as before

Comment: Yes ,but how field are there in one frame of reference and not in other..?

Comment: When you point to the left, someone looking at you from the front will say you are pointing to the right. How is that possible? This is simply a consequence of how we work with vectors/tensors

Comment: And electric field is only a vector in 3d space. In spacetime, both electric and magentic fields *together* form electromagnetic tensor, so your question is a bit like 'how come the horizontal component of a vector vanishes when i rotate it by 90 degrees' (assuming you started with a horizontal vector)

Comment: Ohhk, but still not much clear ,is there anything absolute?

Comment: If you mean invariant with respect to the change between inertial reference frames, then yes, plenty. For instance $\vec E^2-\vec B^2$, or $\vec E \vec B$